# Unable to reset Metrics Counter when Spring Integration is in the classpath

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, codahale-metrics

On my spring-boot application (with spring-integration in classpath), i cannot reset any metrics counter.
It throw ClassCastException :

```
Exception in thread "metricsExecutor-1" org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to handle GenericMessage [payload=delete, headers={timestamp=1435738406974, id=4c9aaac0-8bf1-aac1-d9c9-6f8d50f7801b, metricName=counter.test.toto}] to org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask@2e9f560 in org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.MetricWriterMessageHandler@4dec731e; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.Metric
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.Metric
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.MetricWriterMessageHandler.handleMessage(MetricWriterMessageHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
    ... 3 more
```

I think this is a bug with messageChannel so is there a way to disable it ?

Comment: This looks like a casting error. Can you paste the code where you are passing information as a String to be be casted.

Comment: The ClassCastException is not thrown by my code. It's in a Spring Class. I just do "counter.reset("counter.people.nb");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is sending a message with a `String` payload (`"delete"`) to the channel that the `MetricWriterMessageHandler` is subscribed to. It only expects to see `Delta` or `Metric` payloads.

If you turn on DEBUG logging you should be able to figure out what's sending the bogus message to the channel.

If you determine it's boot code, open an issue against boot in GitHub.

Comment: The "delete" payload is send by Spring and handle by Spring.

Comment: I found this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3062

Comment: Thanks I added [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3378) to avoid the Class Cast, but the issue you found does seem to imply that boot generates the message.

Comment: The payload is sent in this Class : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/writer/MessageChannelMetricWriter.java on line 56. It send a String and the handler only take Delta or Metric

Comment: So, it seems there is a bug, but is there a way to disable the messageHandler to use InMemoryMetricRepository ?

Comment: The issue has been corrected and is available since 1.2.5.RELEASE : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3378